# Z3's running time depends on `smt.qi.eager_threshold`, but the log is the same

Tags: performance, z3, solver, smt, quantifiers

I have two `smt2` files that only differ for the `set-option :smt.qi.eager_threshold` command: one sets it to `30`, the other to `60`. If I run Z3 version 4.8.5 on them, the first takes about 45 seconds to run, and the latter 55 seconds. The difference gets bigger if I further increase `smt.qi.eager_threshold`. I expected that this is because with a higher threshold Z3 instantiates more quantifiers, so I rerun Z3 with `trace=true proof=true` to log all quantifier instantiations as suggested by the [axiom profiler](https://github.com/viperproject/axiom-profiler/tree/8b65072a4becfafa0d4522ffdd3fd8a9bcf1e759#obtaining-logs-from-z3) and [Dafny](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/Investigating-slow-verification-performance#2-running-boogie). With logging enabled Z3 takes much more time to run (5m and 10m, respectively) and, surprisingly, the two logs are almost identical. The only difference is that near the end some identifiers of the form `0x0x7f8404159430` (some pointers?) are not the same, which I think can be ignored. Here is an example from the diff:

```
...
195284,195294c195284,195294
< [new-match] 0x7f8404159430 #60259 #1223 #4938 #107732 ; #109421 (#4956 #4956)
< [new-match] 0x7f8404159468 #68823 #4926 #11519 #11523 ; #109090 (#4902 #4902)
< [new-match] 0x7f84041594a0 #72403 #6078 #11519 #11527 ; #109128 (#6054 #6054)
< [new-match] 0x7f84041594d8 #79964 #6078 #11519 #11527 ; #109128 (#6054 #6054)
< [new-match] 0x7f8404159510 #77477 #7869 #11519 #11531 ; #109155 (#7434 #7434)
< [new-match] 0x7f8404159548 #80168 #7869 #11519 #11531 ; #109155 (#7434 #7434)
< [new-match] 0x7f8404159580 #895 #894 #107821 #1141 ; #109377
< [new-match] 0x7f84041595b8 #895 #894 #107864 #1141 ; #109400
< [new-match] 0x7f84041595f0 #12897 #647 #4938 ; #4956
< [new-match] 0x7f8404159620 #648 #647 #4938 ; #4956
< [new-match] 0x7f8404159650 #12793 #647 #4938 ; #4956
---
> [new-match] 0x7fa96b39c230 #60259 #1223 #4938 #107732 ; #109421 (#4956 #4956)
> [new-match] 0x7fa96b39c268 #68823 #4926 #11519 #11523 ; #109090 (#4902 #4902)
> [new-match] 0x7fa96b39c2a0 #72403 #6078 #11519 #11527 ; #109128 (#6054 #6054)
> [new-match] 0x7fa96b39c2d8 #79964 #6078 #11519 #11527 ; #109128 (#6054 #6054)
> [new-match] 0x7fa96b39c310 #77477 #7869 #11519 #11531 ; #109155 (#7434 #7434)
> [new-match] 0x7fa96b39c348 #80168 #7869 #11519 #11531 ; #109155 (#7434 #7434)
> [new-match] 0x7fa96b39c380 #895 #894 #107821 #1141 ; #109377
> [new-match] 0x7fa96b39c3b8 #895 #894 #107864 #1141 ; #109400
> [new-match] 0x7fa96b39c3f0 #12897 #647 #4938 ; #4956
> [new-match] 0x7fa96b39c420 #648 #647 #4938 ; #4956
> [new-match] 0x7fa96b39c450 #12793 #647 #4938 ; #4956
...
```

My question is: *How can the running time vary so much if Z3's log is the same?* Is it just because in the second run Z3 allocates bigger data structures, even if the proof exploration is the same?

I did some measurements and the cause doesn't seem to be Z3's seed. Apparently, for my smt2 file there is an optimal value of `smt.qi.eager_threshold`. Increasing that, Z3 takes (exponentially) more time but the log stays the same. Decreasing that, Z3 still takes more time, but as expected some `unsat` answers change to `unknown` and the log changes too.

---

The options used in my smt2 files:

```
(set-option :auto_config false)
(set-option :type_check true)
(set-option :smt.case_split 3)
(set-option :smt.delay_units true)
(set-option :smt.arith.solver 2)
(set-option :smt.mbqi false)
(set-option :model.compact false)
(set-option :model.v2 true)
(set-option :pp.bv_literals false)
```

Z3's statistics on the first file, with `trace=true proof=true`:

```
(:added-eqs            294
 :arith-assert-lower   1
 :arith-assert-upper   5
 :arith-eq-adapter     1
 :conflicts            1
 :del-clause           90
 :max-generation       2
 :max-memory           527.79
 :memory               23.39
 :mk-bool-var          6726
 :mk-clause            5174
 :num-allocs           87550496
 :num-checks           1
 :propagations         5105
 :quant-instantiations 78
 :rlimit-count         278808
 :time                 0.01
 :total-time           300.06)
```

Z3's statistics on the second file, with `trace=true proof=true`:

```
(:added-eqs            294
 :arith-assert-lower   1
 :arith-assert-upper   5
 :arith-eq-adapter     1
 :conflicts            1
 :del-clause           90
 :max-generation       2
 :max-memory           682.75
 :memory               23.39
 :mk-bool-var          6726
 :mk-clause            5174
 :num-allocs           147909479
 :num-checks           1
 :propagations         5105
 :quant-instantiations 78
 :rlimit-count         278808
 :time                 0.01
 :total-time           617.86)
```

Interestingly, `num-allocs` is 70% higher in the second case.

Comment: Adding `proof=true` changes the solver behaviour (e.g. it disables everything for which we don't have proof construction). Do you observe the same runtime difference after adding that option?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger "Adding proof=true changes the solver behaviour" – Do you have a reference to that? Both the documentation of the [axiom profiler](https://github.com/viperproject/axiom-profiler/tree/8b65072a4becfafa0d4522ffdd3fd8a9bcf1e759#obtaining-logs-from-z3) and of [Dafny](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/Investigating-slow-verification-performance#2-running-boogie) suggest to use `trace=true proof=true` to debug performance.

Comment: “Do you observe the same runtime difference after adding that option?” – I fixed the question: 5m and 10m were with logging enabled. Without `trace=true proof=true` Z3 takes much less (45s with smt.qi.eager_threshold at 30, 55s at 60, 98s at 100) but the logs still don’t have differences except for those `0x…` pointers. With `trace=true` but without `proof=true` Z3 crashes with a “Segmentation fault: 11”.

Comment: Re reference: see the various `if (proofs_enabled) ...` and similar in the Z3 source code. For the segfault, please submit an issue in the Z3 issue tracker, that's likely a trivial thing to fix.

Comment: With Z3 4.8.12 I do not get the segfault, so I'll not report that.